# Why echo is printing string variables before additional text that have been merged with it?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, variable, string, echo

I have code in bash for making latex file and in this fragment I want to make a table in a loop:

```
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == *"comment"* ]]; then
      
      echo "${line#*comment: }" >> tif_list.txt
      
      IN="${line#*comment: }"
      
      data="$(echo $IN | tr "," "\n")"
      
      echo "       ${data[0]}" >> table.tex #name
      echo "     & ${data[2]}" >> table.tex #longitude
      echo "     & ${data[3]}" >> table.tex #latitude
      echo "     & ${data[4]}, ${data[5]}, ${data[6]}, ${data[7]}, ${data[8]}, ${data[9]}, " >> table.tex #dimensions
      echo "     & ${data[10]}" >> table.tex #time
      echo "     & ${data[1]}" >> table.tex #comments
      echo "     & \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{${tif%.*}.png}\\" >> table.tex #adress
      echo "    \hline" >> table.tex
      echo "" >> table.tex
      
    fi    
  done < tif_info.txt
  
done
```

but echo first prints variables, and then my additional text:

```
     \hline
       Target0001
The operator places target notes here. Multiple lines OK.
55:51.6217 N
020:34.4421 E
C1
L3.0
W0.8
H1-1.0
H2-1.0
D16.8
2021:11:13 08:29:02.37
     & 
     & 
     & , , , , , , 
     & 
     & 
     & \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Target0001.png}\
    \hline
```

I want:

```
     \hline
     Target0001
     & The operator places target notes here. Multiple lines OK.
     & 55:51.6217 N
     & 020:34.4421 E
     & C1, L3.0, W0.8, H1-1.0, H2-1.0, D16.8 
     & 2021:11:13 08:29:02.37
     & \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Target0001.png}\
    \hline
```

I was trying to add /& or merge text by += but it doesn't change anything.
I just need to make it work so I could have table with pictures and metadata from my tiff pictures.

My whole code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#program pobiera metadane tiff i zestawia w tabeli

echo "Starting..."

echo "\documentclass{article}" > table.tex
echo "\usepackage{graphicx, tabularx}" >> table.tex
echo "\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}" >> table.tex
echo "\graphicspath{ {./images/} }" >> table.tex
echo "" >> table.tex
echo "\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}" >> table.tex
echo "\newcolumntype{b}{X}" >> table.tex
echo "\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}" >> table.tex
echo "" >> table.tex
echo "\begin{document}" >> table.tex
echo "" >> table.tex
echo "\begin{table}[htbp]" >> table.tex
echo "    \centering" >> table.tex
echo "    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} { " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}s " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}s " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}s " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}s " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}s " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}b " >> table.tex
echo "      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}b | }" >> table.tex
echo "     \hline" >> table.tex
echo "     name & longitude & latitude & dimensions & time & comments & picture \\" >> table.tex
echo "     \hline" >> table.tex

echo "Serching comment..."

for tif in *.tif; do
  [ -f "$tif" ] || break
  identify -verbose "$tif" > tif_info.txt 2>&1
  
  #convert "$tif" "${tif%.*}.png" 2>&1

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" == *"comment"* ]]; then
      
      echo "${line#*comment: }" >> tif_list.txt
      
      IN="${line#*comment: }"
      
      data="$(echo $IN | tr "," "\n")"
      
      echo "       ${data[0]}" >> table.tex #name
      echo "     & ${data[2]}" >> table.tex #longitude
      echo "     & ${data[3]}" >> table.tex #latitude
      echo "     & ${data[4]}, ${data[5]}, ${data[6]}, ${data[7]}, ${data[8]}, ${data[9]}, " >> table.tex #dimensions
      echo "     & ${data[10]}" >> table.tex #time
      echo "     & ${data[1]}" >> table.tex #comments
      echo "     & \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{${tif%.*}.png}\\" >> table.tex #adress
      echo "    \hline" >> table.tex
      echo "" >> table.tex
      
    fi    
  done < tif_info.txt
  
done

echo "    \hline" >> table.tex
echo "    \end{tabularx}" >> table.tex
echo "\end{table}" >> table.tex
echo "" >> table.tex
echo "\end{document}" >> table.tex
echo "" >> table.tex

echo "Process completed."
```

Comment: You're using `$data` as if it is an array, but it's not. Also, please add expected output. You should also prefer `printf` over `echo` , but for text processing, you might want to use `awk` and not `bash` in the first place.

Comment: What is $data? I was using this for cutting the string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash

Comment: You just change `,` to `\n`, it's still a string.

Comment: Thank you, that explains where I've made mistake. I will try to use printf, I did not used awk because I don't know it.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you [learn the basics of perl scripting](https://www.perltutorial.org/introduction-to-perl/).  Generating TeX output (and similar text processing tasks) is trivial in perl, much easier than trying to do it in sh....and runs much faster too.   BTW, I routinely use perl to generate tables, TOCs, hyperref links, etc for TeX documents, because perl is **good** at text processing.  Shell is not, it is lousy at text processing...it is, however, good at co-ordinating the execution of other programs, such as awk, sed, perl, grep, and many more.

Comment: See also questions about perl on the TeX SE site, e.g, [How to generate LaTeX documents with Perl](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21928/how-to-generate-latex-documents-with-perl).  Also googling for "perl tex" or "perl latex" will come up with lots of blog posts like [USING PERL IN YOUR LaTeX DESIGN FLOW](https://jwebb-design.com/ee/howto/using_perl_with_latex.shtml)

Answer (score 2):

```
data="$(echo $IN | tr "," "\n")"
```

This is a scalar assignment, so you get a scalar variable. It'll contain a single multi-line string. (You could check with `declare -p data`.) In Bash,`$var` and `${var[0]}` access the same element, regardless of the type of the variable. Either the one at index `0` if it's an array, or the lone value if it's a scalar.

You probably want to use `read -a` instead, e.g.

```
IN=foo,bar,doo
IFS=, read -r -a data  <<< "$IN"
echo "${#data[@]}" "${data[1]}"   # prints '3 bar'
```

---

In the stackexchange question you linked to, there's this:

```
mails=$(echo $IN | tr ";" "\n")
for addr in $mails
do ...
```

There, it's the unquoted expansion of `$mails` in the `for` loop that splits the contents on whitespace (or rather, whatever `IFS` contains, but by default it's whitespace). Now, that *works*, and you could similarly assign the result to an array with `arr=($mails)`,  **but** it'll split on *any* whitespace, *and* it'll process filename patterns, so values like `foo bar` and `*` will be trouble. See e.g
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting and [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

The top answer there has the same `read -a` that I wrote above. You want the `-r` too, to prevent it from messing up backslashes.

Comment: It works! I can't upvote but it helped me.

Comment: Now I see that I missed this solution. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @KarolinaPomian, well, meh. The worst that happens to the question is that it gets forgotten among the, umm, apparently 200 000+ other questions. Also you might not be able to, since there's an upvoted answer, and in theory someone might chance upon just this one and it might be helpful, and if you get a lot of deleted questions, the system stops taking questions from you (but no one will know if you just create a new account). Don't think too much about it...